# Speed up apply with custom function, convert to lapply?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I'm trying to speed up a workflow that involves multiplying rows from two data frames together via a custom function.

Right now I'm using apply() with a custom function. My understanding is that lapply() or sapply() would be faster (and eventually allow parallelization, though I'd prefer a speedup that does not depend on parallel processing), but I can't figure out the lapply() or sapply() syntax I should use with my custom function. If there's an even simpler way to vectorize the custom function and avoid *apply() altogether, that would be preferred.

The number of rows in my use case will be 1 million or more, and the number of columns will be around 15, but here's a MWE that illustrates the speed issue:

```
# Two data frames that will be used in the calculation. d2 can be a matrix, but d1 must be a data frame.
d1 <- data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = runif(1000), V3 = runif(1000), V4 = runif(1000))
d2 <- data.frame(Va = runif(3), V1 = runif(3), V2 = runif(3), V3 = runif(3), V4 = runif(3))

# Custom function that is applied to each row in d1
manualprob <- function(x){

    xb1 <- as.numeric(rowSums(d2[1,2:ncol(d2)] * x) + d2[1,1])
    xb2 <- as.numeric(rowSums(d2[2,2:ncol(d2)] * x) + d2[2,1])
    xb3 <- as.numeric(rowSums(d2[3,2:ncol(d2)] * x) + d2[3,1])

    denom <- 1 + exp(xb1) + exp(xb2) + exp(xb3)
    prob <- exp(xb1)/denom

    return(prob)
    }

# apply() used below, but it is too slow
start_time <- proc.time()

d1$prob <- as.vector(apply(d1, 1, manualprob))

proc.time() - start_time
   user  system elapsed 
  1.081   0.007   1.088
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to convert to matrices and use R's very fast matrix operations...

You can create all of the xb figures in one go with

```
xb <- as.matrix(d2[, -1]) %*% t(as.matrix(d1)) + d2[, 1]
```

This produces a 3*1000 matrix.

And then you can get the probabilities with

```
prob <- exp(xb[1, ]) / (1 + colSums(exp(xb)))
```

This all takes almost zero time on my machine!